# cURL Time Out on Server but Not on Localhost

Tags: php, curl, timeout

Stuck with this particular issue. I have code that get lots of pages from a forum i.e.  www.q8yat.net . Now I have a loop that uses curl to get the pages from the forum. Everything works fine on my localhost. BUt when I upload the files on my server and try to get the pages I get a connection timeout error usually after a fixed amount of pages are loaded but thats not always. The curl options I am using are :

```
$options = array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
     CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
     CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
     CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
     CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 1,      // timeout on connect
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 1200,      // timeout on response
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects

 );
```

phpinfo of my server: http://topics4today.com/public/02_12_2010/fcrawl/src/phpinfo.php

Ok i believe the forum is using an apache module:' mod_bwlimited'  to limit the amount of data I can request based on my ip. A possibility.

Comment: Have you tried increasing CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT?

Comment: @igorw - yes, OP does `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 1`

Comment: Did you set the PHP timeout? http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @ajreal yeah, but setting it to a value beyond 1?

Comment: @Pekka - possible, maybe OP having some network issue on his server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the forum is using an apache module:' mod_bwlimited' to limit the amount of data I can request based on my ip. Issue can be solved by requesting only a limited number of pages in every run of the script. E.g. your script runs, asks for 2 pages, stops, then starts again ( using javascript timer ) and asks for 2 more pages and this goes on in a loop.

Comment: consider pay extra $ to get rid of this constraints

Comment: Well the solution has to be independent of any particular forum we are requesting data from